# Custom jQuery show/hide div JS not working in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, master-pages, scriptmanager

I have a master page that have script manager and Javascript/Jquery added in it. See below:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="SM" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Custom.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Custom Js:

```
$(".section").click(function () {  
    if ($(this).next(".sectiondetail").is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).next(".sectiondetail").slideDown("slow");
        $(this).children('span').text('[-]');
} else {
        $(this).next(".sectiondetail").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).children('span').text('[+]');
}
});
```

I have placed following html in my ASCX control that is added in content page that uses my master page:

```
<div class="section">
    <span>[+]</span> General Information
</div>
<div class="sectiondetail" style="display: none;">
     Details go here.
</div>
```

The JS function does not work as expected. If i add JS function in my ASCX control page, it works as expected. What is wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Try with $(".section").live('click', function () {  ... });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time you are binding click event you may not have html controls ready/rendered with css `section`. `On` will make sure to add click event even the elements are added or rendered after this script block bind click.

```
$(".section").on("click", function () {  
    if ($(this).next(".sectiondetail").is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).next(".sectiondetail").slideDown("slow");
        $(this).children('span').text('[-]');
} else {
        $(this).next(".sectiondetail").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).children('span').text('[+]');
}
});
```

Or You can bind event when document is ready.

```
$(function(){
$(".section").click(function () {  
    if ($(this).next(".sectiondetail").is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).next(".sectiondetail").slideDown("slow");
        $(this).children('span').text('[-]');
} else {
        $(this).next(".sectiondetail").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).children('span').text('[+]');
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `style="visibility: hidden;"` instead of `style="display: none;"`

```
<div class="sectiondetail" style="visibility: hidden;">
    Details go here.
</div>
```

If you are using following code,

```
$(this).next(".sectiondetail").is(":hidden")
```

OR You may Use;

```
$(this).next(".sectiondetail").css('display') == 'none'
```

In your current scenario i.e. `style="display: none;"`